# Python recursively appending list function

Tags: python, recursion

Having issues with a recursive function that should be relatively simple to do, but can`t seem to get right.

I have a folder structure with folders that can contain other folders, images or files. Associated with each folder there are permissions. I want to have my function recursively build a list of the permissions that are associated with each folder.

I have a function `has_read_permission(request)` that returns `True` if the folder has permissions and `False` if not

I have built a function like so:

```
def get_child_perms(self, folder, request, perm_list):
        # Folder contains other folders
        if folder.get_children():
            # For every sub-folder
            for subfolder in folder.get_children():
                return perm_list.append(self.get_child_perms(subfolder, request, perm_list))
        else:
            # If folder doesn't have sub-folders containing folders
            return [folder.has_read_permission(request)]
```

I keep getting None

Given folders like so:

```
Folder (allowed) - Wont check this one
|_First Folder (allowed)
| |_First sub Folder (restricted)
| | |_File
| | |_File
| | |_Image
| |__Second Sub Folder (allowed)
|_Second Folder (allowed)
```

Then running `get_child_perms()` would return 
[True,False,True,True]
or even
[True, [False, True], True]

**EDIT**

Disregard edit -> asked other question [Python Recursive function missing results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103424/python-recursive-function-missing-results)

Changed abit,

```
def get_child_perms(self, folder, request, perm_list):
        if folder.get_children():
            for subfolder in folder.get_children():
                perm_list.append(self.get_child_perms(subfolder, request, perm_list))
            return perm_list
        else:
            return [folder.has_read_permission(request)]
```

getting:

```
[[True], [...], [True], [...], [...], [True], [True], [True], [True], [True], [True], [True], [True], [...], [True], [...]]

 Admin
 -Folder 1
   - Files
 -Folder 2
   - Files
 -Folder 3
   - Files 
 -Folder 4
   - SubFolder 1
      -SubSubFolder 1
         - Files
      - Files
   - SubFolder 2
      - SubSubFolder 2
           - Files
      - Files
 -Folder 5
   - SubFolder 3
       - Files
   - SubFolder 4
       - Files
   - SubFolder 5
       -Files
   - Files
 -Folder 6
   - Files
 -Folder 7
   - SubFoler 6
       - Files
   - Files
 -Folder 8
   - Files
```

Comment: Try to answer this question, will the `for` loop's body be executed if `folder.get_children()` returns and empty iterable?

Comment: Are you sure you want to `return` inside the loop? That will make it exit after at most one iteration.

Comment: Ya removed that return in loop

Comment: I don't understand your latest edit. If someone here solved your problem (i.e., you are no longer getting `None`), you should mark an answer accepted. Ask a new question if you have one, but you can't just keep editing this one until the function works just how you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out append is an *inplace* operation that returns None, you can avoid using `append` at all by returning a list comp:

```
def get_child_perms(self, folder, request, perm_list):
    # Folder contains other folders
    children =  folder.get_children()
    if children:
        # For every sub-folder
        return [self.get_child_perms(subfolder, request, perm_list)
                for subfolder in children]
    return [folder.has_read_permission(request)]
```

You don't need an else either as you can only return once from the function.

Comment: This seems to work, but not returning values for nested folders, only returns values of folder that contain only files

Comment: Add a link to your code, I think there is a simpler way to do what you want

Comment: http://dpaste.com/2ZYA3QB here the code for the plugin, but not sure what you want to see, since this is a plugin for django cms, which is based on django-filer.

Comment: Do you actually want boolean values returned based on permissions and only interested in folders?

Comment: I think you need to `return [folder.has_read_permission(request)]+ [self.get_child_perms(subfolder...`, you will need to flatten the the returned list if you want a flatten list, `itertools.chain` will do it

Answer (score 4):

```
for subfolder in folder.get_children():
    perm_list.append(self.get_child_perms(subfolder, request, perm_list))
return perm_list
```

`.append` is in place. It does not return anything.So you are getting `None`

Answer (score 3):

In-place list methods return `None` to remind you that they operate in place.

Instead of:

```
return permlist.append(self.get_child_perms(...  # etc.
```

Try:

```
permlist.append(self.get_child_perms(...
return permlist
```

Edited to add: As other comments/answers have pointed out, you'll want to return outside your `for` loop if you want it to complete.