# Python Recursive function missing results

Tags: python, recursion

Coming from [Python recursively appending list function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102420/python-recursively-appending-list-function) 
Trying to recursively get a list of permissions associated with a file structure.

I have this function:

```
def get_child_perms(self, folder, request, perm_list):
        # Folder contains other folders
        if folder.get_children():
            # For every sub-folder
            return [self.get_child_perms(subfolder, request, perm_list) for subfolder in folder.get_children()]
        return folder.has_read_permission(request)
```

That returns all the results except the folders that contain other folders.

```
folder <- Missing (allowed)
    subfolder <- Missing (restricted)
        subsubfolder <- Get this (restricted)
            files
```

Output from function would be 
[True, False, False]

another case would be, where A = allowed, R = restricted

```
folder  A
    subfolder   A
        subsubfolder    R
            files
        files
    subfolder   R
        files
    subfolder   A
        subsubfolder    A
            files
        files
    subfolder   A
        files
    files
```

Output would be 
[True,True,False,False,True,True,True]

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Seems like list is not the correct choice of data structure in your case.

Comment: @AnandSKumar and others, for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102420/python-recursively-appending-list-function

Comment: I know there is a way to recursively store build perm_list to hold all these results, also added output for simple case

Comment: Are you sure you want them all in a flattened list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue occurs you are only returning the `folder permission` , when folder does not have any children , when it has children, you are not including the `folder.has_read_permission(request)` in your return result , which is most probably causing you issue. You need to do -

```
def get_child_perms(self, folder, request, perm_list):
        # Folder contains other folders
        if folder.get_children():
            # For every sub-folder
            return [folder.has_read_permission(request)] + [self.get_child_perms(subfolder, request, perm_list) for subfolder in folder.get_children()]
        return [folder.has_read_permission(request)]
```

This should result in (not tested) -

```
[folderperm [subfolderperm [subsubfolderperm]]
```

---

Comment: Works perfectly, list is not flattened but might be better

Answer (score 0):

why not  [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk)

> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place
>   (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be
>   used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even
>   to inform walk() about directories the caller creates or renames
>   before it resumes walk() again. Modifying dirnames when topdown is
>   False is ineffective, because in bottom-up mode the directories in
>   dirnames are generated before dirpath itself is generated.

for example you can build generator (lazy list) that generates only non restricted directories

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk("top_path"):
    if restricted(dirpath):
        del dirnames
        continue
    yield (dirpath,tuple(filenames))
```

Comment: Not an actual filesystem, just django-filer

Comment: when you can yield booleans